# I’m looking for the owner of patent BR6702630U

Tags: international, inventor, contact, brazil

how do I find contact information for the owner of this patent from Brazil: BR6702630U GRAPHIC AND PRINTING PROCESS IN PHOTOGRAPHS by inventor Norbert Egon Goldbergs?

Comment: The patent cited is almost guaranteed to be expired by now. This means you don't need to license the invention from the inventor or assignee.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, only the inventor is listed so he is likely the owner of the patent. The patent's priority date is in 1987 so the patent is almost guaranteed to be expired by now. This means the invention is no longer protected and licensing is not required. In fact, it isn't even clear if a patent was granted as the cited number is listed as an application in [Google Patents](https://patents.google.com/patent/BR6702630U/en?oq=BR6702630U%20). I'm not experienced with Brazilian patents. As for the inventor, a Google search generates useful info.